# Label animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a transition effect on my label so that it comes out from the left side of the view and centre itself in the middle of the screen. I am doing:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label.center.x -= view.bounds.width

}
```

to place the label out of the view, but this is not working as the label is still present in the view. Please help.

Comment: If you are using Autolayout and have a constraint to center your label you can not simply just change the center of the label, you need to animate one of the constraints.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `label.center.x -= view.bounds.width` will make it appear at the left of the view, so you can't see any effect on it.

You can use `UIView.animateWithDuration` to make animation effect:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: [.CurveEaseOut], animations: {
      label.center.x += view.bounds.width 
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

And you should put them in your `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`, so everytime your view is resume, it will animate your label. Your code will look like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    label.center.x = view.center.x // Place it in the center x of the view.
    label.center.x -= view.bounds.width // Place it on the left of the view with the width = the bounds'width of the view.
    // animate it from the left to the right
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: [.CurveEaseOut], animations: {
          label.center.x += view.bounds.width
          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

This will make your `label` appear from the left to the right.

Comment: This is the correct way programmatically, but the animateWithDuration should be placed in viewDidAppear to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Please can anyone explain what " label.center.x -= view.bounds.width" is doing. i cannot understand the math behind it.

Comment: That means you place your `label` to the left with the range = the width of your view.

Comment: Thanks Khuong, it works like a charm but only one thing when the label is coming out from the left it is not performing smooth transition instead, it kind of stop in the middle then move. can you suggest some change

Comment: say the width of the screen is 400 and my label is placed at 200 then the code " label.centre.x -= view.bounds.width" means " label.center.x = label.center.x - view.bounds.width" which is equal to 200- 400 = -200 . is that what is going on khuong

Comment: Did you use AutoLayout for your `label`?

Comment: See my code. First I set your `label` in the center x of the `view`, then I place it to the left with the range = the width of the view, then I animate `label` to move from the left to the center x of the `view` by `label.center.x += view.bounds.width`. If you use as my solution, you don't need to set AutoLayout for it.

Comment: no i did not use autolayout. i just placed it randomly Khuong

Comment: the code which you write works like a charm but only when the label comes out it is not smooth transition but stops in the middle then moves to the middle

Comment: **Swift 5** Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit...

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 5**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    label.center.x = view.center.x // Place it in the center x of the view.
    label.center.x -= view.bounds.width // Place it on the left of the view with the width = the bounds'width of the view.
    // animate it from the left to the right
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
        self.label.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for Swift 3

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {

            label = self.view.frame.size.width / 2
        }
```

make sure that the label is initially positioned away from the screen.